# Create var inside of each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, each, var

I have an array with some numbers:

```
var bullet = [ 0, 39, 42, 89, 115 ];
```

And created an each loop

```
$.each(bullet, function( index, value ) {

});
```

Now I want to create a variable with the index as part of the name for each item.
Like so:

```
var bullet + index = document.getElementById("bullet_" + index);
```

It should look like that:

```
var bullet0 = document.getElementById("bullet_0");
var bullet1 = document.getElementById("bullet_1");
```

And so on...

But my code does not work - it always sais
**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier**

Comment: That's... not a good idea.

Comment: Use an array like you did for `bullet`

Comment: I think you need to explain **why** you're doing this? As I'm pretty sure your coming at it from the wrong way.

Comment: try simply array or js object

Comment: Not a good idea, but here you go. 
`window['bullet' + index] = document.getElementById("bullet_" + index);`

Comment: Yes because that is a **Syntax Error**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't create dynamic variable names. You can, however, create dynamic keys, by creating a wrapper object, and assigning the would-be variables as properties of that object:

```
var bullets = {};

$.each(bullet, function( index, value ) {
    bullets[ index ] = ( document.getElementById( 'bullet_' + index ) );
});
```

Better still, you could use an array (since the keys would be numeric):

```
var bullets = [];

$.each(bullet, function( index, value ) {
    bullets.push( document.getElementById( 'bullet_' + index ) );
});
```

In either case, rather than your proposed access method of

```
bullet0;
bullet1;
```

You would access the elements as follows:

```
bullet[ 0 ];
bullet[ 1 ];
```

Comment: Is this a perfect use case for `map()`?

Comment: @Pavlo I believe it is — in fact I would definitely recommend [Jack's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21111390/356541) over this. I'll keep this here because the elaboration could be quite useful — and for browsers that don't support `map` natively, the method above is essentially taking place under the covers anyway.

Answer (score 3):

What you're probably looking for is [`jQuery.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) instead of `jQuery.each()`:

```
var bullets = $.map(bullet, function(value, index) {
    return document.getElementById('bullet_' + index);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Using underscorejs#map http://underscorejs.org/#map

```
_.map([1,2,3,4], function(index) { 
   return document.getElementById('bullet_' + index);
});
```

Comment: Why should he? [Native `map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) has been available for ages, so is [jQuery `map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) There is no need to add new library to the project just for that.

Comment: @Pavlo More importantly, OP is using jQuery. I don't believe native map is available for IE8.

Comment: @Jack since there are no such limitation in the question, it would be natural to assume ES5-capable browser.

Comment: @Pavlo Natural until your boss whacks you on the head because he gets a JavaScript error on his browser ;-)

Comment: @Jack are you a professional developer? Your spec's support table either includes IE8 or it doesn't.

Comment: @Pavlo Sure, but it's not about me :) jQuery is used, so there's no compelling reason to use native methods and potentially break stuff.

Comment: @Pavlo You are right. Native map() is good for this case, but using underscore has some advantages - [powerful collections](http://underscorejs.org/#collections), [modern browser support](http://underscorejs.org/test/), [method chaining](http://underscorejs.org/#chaining) and elegant api. To solve complex business problem, I used underscore as basic more than native.